# phonegap filetransfer.download method is synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: cordova

If `filetransfer.download()` method is **async** then tell me **how to make this method sync**.

```
ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, function(entry) {
  alert("successfully downloaded" + entry.fullpath);
  console.log("success" + entry.filepath);
  localpath.push(entry.filepath);
}, fail, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap / Cordova works asynchronously so if you want to perform the downloads in a not async fashion you have trigger your required code inside the download success callback that will ensure that the download was successful, or in the error callback if needed.

If you execute the download and then other code after it it will continue with the other code as you noted because of the async nature. So basically always use the callbacks if you want to perform certain actions in sequence.

Here part of my code that will give you and idea.

```
function DownloadFile ( serverFileURL, fileFullPath, fileName, dwnldSuccess, dwnldWError )
{
    // Create and configure the file transfer object to download the file
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(serverFileURL);

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        fileFullPath,
        function ( entry ){
            dwnldSuccess ( entry, fileName ); // Your success code will be here or trigger your desired function.
        },
        function ( error ){
            dwnldWError ( error, fileName ); // Your failure code will be here or trigger your desired function.
        },
        false       
    );
}
```

Comment: but what to do when You need to synchronously download files in loop as a one of many attributes?